# Django group sublist permission

Tags: django, permissions

I need to restrict user permission to a sublist of groups.

For example, I have a user USER1 who belongs to groups GROUP1, GROUP2 and ADMIN.

At connection the user can choose to connect with

- ADMIN permissions
- or GROUP1 permissions exclusively (without other groups permissions)
- or GROUP2 permissions exclusively
- or GROUP1 + GROUP2 permissions

Is it possible to do this in Django ?

Regards,

Comment: No, user belonging to certain group has group's permissions. You would have to modify group membership each time user logs in, which is ugly.

Comment: I agree but I must do it. So if the 'best' solution is modify group membership each time user logs... I will do it ! ugly or not...